# What is the angle between two intersecting tangents to a circle?

Tags: geometry

A circle of radius $r$ with centre $C$ is located at distance $d$ from a point $P$.

There are two tangents to the circle which pass through point $P$ - one on each side. They intersect the circle at points $A$ and $B$.

What is the angle through $P$ between these two tangents? In other words, angle $APB$?

I know that angle $APB$ + angle $ACB$ add up to 180.

(Not homework, for graphics programming)
Thanks,
Louise

Comment: What kind of graphics programming problem?

Comment: Recursive 2D radial tree layout with arbitrarily sized nodes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture:

[image]

$\overline {CP} = d$

$\angle CAP$ and $\angle BAP$ are right angles, and $\triangle APB$ is isosceles.

$m\angle APC = \arcsin \frac rd\\
m\angle APB = 2\arcsin \frac rd\\
m\angle BAP = \arccos \frac rd$

Comment: Thank you! How did you generate the picture?

Comment: I use MS Paint.

Answer (score 0):

I presume "at distance $d$" means that $|CP|=r+d$.

The triangle $ACP$ is right angled, with $|AC|=r$. Then
$$\sin\angle APC=\frac{r}{r+d}.$$
Then
$$\angle ABP=2\angle APC=2\sin^{-1}\frac r{r+d}.$$